# Can I detect whether a footnote has been split?

Tags: page-breaking, tex-core, footnotes, output-routine

Title sez it all: Can I detect, hopefully by inspecting `\box\footins`, whether a footnote has been split at page-breaking?

I found the package [fnbreak](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fnbreak) but it uses labels, which is much too delayed for my purpose.

I thought about a mark, but where would I put `\splitbotmarks`?

Of course I could put a special penalty after every footnote and try to detect that with `\lastpenalty`, but it seems like a cheap trick and furthermore, maybe it would be discarded?

What would you do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the TeX output routine the number of split insertions is available in the register `\insertpenalties`. So as long as footnotes are the only insertions that can split (e.g., as it is the case with LaTeX) you can simply inspect this parameter to find out if a footnote has been split. From the TeX book:

> Chapter 15 points out that \TeX\ gives special values to
>   certain internal registers and parameters, in addition to |\box255|,
>   just before the output routine begins. Insertions are put into their
>   own vboxes, and ^|\insertpenalties| is set equal to the total number of
>   heldover insertions; furthermore the ^|\outputpenalty| parameter is
>   set to the value of the penalty at the current breakpoint. An output
>   routine can be made to do special things when these quantities have
>   special values. For example, the output routine of plain \TeX\ recognizes
>   a ^|\supereject| (which ejects all held-over insertions) by the fact that
>   |\supereject| causes |\outputpenalty| to be $-20000$, and by using
>   |\insertpenalties| to decide if any insertions are being held over.

Comment: When I tested this I got `\insertpenalties=1` even if a footnote was moved entirely to the next page. But I can test it again. Maybe I was unclear with "split": I want to produce a continuation mark, so I'm only interested in footnotes which are really split in two parts.

Comment: Hmm. I can't reproduce getting `\insertpenalties>0` without a split footnote. So I must have been deceived the last time I tested this. Thank yout for pointing this out!

Answer (score 8):

You could arrange for each note to end with a strut that's 2 or 3 sp deeper than normal so if the depth of the box isn't recognisable you know it doesn't end with a line with the market strut.

Comment: That's also a good idea. But I'd need to remove it afterwards because I'm column-balancing footnotes...